Could someone provide a simple example sentence for the verb 「意味する」?
I am studying for JLPT N5 and I came across this verb. I know it means "to give/have meaning" but I'm not sure in which situation i could use this. Would a sentence like 「これは何を意味していますか」be okay? If not, please provide an example sentence! Thank you.

https://massif.la/ja/search?q=%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%E3%82%92%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

@JimmyYang Unfortunately it's not the perfect match...

But what do you intend to say by これは何を意味していますか in the question?
